Understanding the Derivation of a Formula Involving Binomial Coefficients and Factorials
I'm studying a formula that involves binomial coefficients and factorials, and I'm struggling to understand how it was derived.
The image below is a  screenshot from the paper. They are taking the ratio of the hypergeometric and binomial distribution. $N$ is the population size $n$ is the sample size and $k$ is the number of successes in the total population.

I dont get how they got to the final step.

If you want a response, type it in using mathjax. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Hint: $\frac{k!}{(k-x)!k^x}=\prod_{j=1}^{x-1}[1-(j/k)]$. Group likewise the other terms to obtain the two other $\prod_{j=1}^{\dots}$.
